Database upgrade failed due to error - Liferay 7.4
I am trying to upgrade DB from Liferay 7.2 to 7.4 but its failing and giving below error.
Initially, we have found that the verified column in release_ table was in bit and I have got an error to change it to boolean, now after changing it to boolean, I am getting this error.
2024-05-23 10:12:50.316 INFO  [main][PortalUpgradeProcess:335] Failed upgrade process com.liferay.portal.upgrade.PortalUpgradeProcess in 243 ms
2024-05-23 10:12:50.327 ERROR [main][DBUpgrader:70] null
com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogSanitizerException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bit = boolean_  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts._  Position: 143 [Sanitized]
    at com.liferay.portal.upgrade.PortalUpgradeProcess.upgrade(PortalUpgradeProcess.java:329) ~[portal-impl.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.util.UpgradeProcessUtil._upgradeProcess(UpgradeProcessUtil.java:172) ~[portal-kernel.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.util.UpgradeProcessUtil.upgradeProcess(UpgradeProcessUtil.java:148) ~[portal-kernel.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupHelperUtil.upgradeProcess(StartupHelperUtil.java:160) ~[portal-impl.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.tools.DBUpgrader.upgradePortal(DBUpgrader.java:296) ~[portal-impl.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.tools.DBUpgrader.main(DBUpgrader.java:166) [portal-impl.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.tools.db.upgrade.client.DBUpgraderLauncher.main(DBUpgraderLauncher.java:45) [com.liferay.portal.tools.db.upgrade.client.jar:?]
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogSanitizerException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bit = boolean_  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts._  Position: 143 [Sanitized]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeProcess.upgrade(UpgradeProcess.java:128) ~[portal-kernel.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeProcess.upgrade(UpgradeProcess.java:146) ~[portal-kernel.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.upgrade.PortalUpgradeProcess.doUpgrade(PortalUpgradeProcess.java:350) ~[portal-impl.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.upgrade.PortalUpgradeProcess.upgrade(PortalUpgradeProcess.java:324) ~[portal-impl.jar:?]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogSanitizerException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bit = boolean_  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts._  Position: 143 [Sanitized]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676) ~[postgresql.jar:42.4.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366) ~[postgresql.jar:42.4.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356) ~[postgresql.jar:42.4.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496) ~[postgresql.jar:42.4.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413) ~[postgresql.jar:42.4.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190) ~[postgresql.jar:42.4.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:134) ~[postgresql.jar:42.4.3]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[hikaricp.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[hikaricp.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v7_4_x.UpgradeRegion.doUpgrade(UpgradeRegion.java:42) ~[portal-impl.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeProcess.lambda$upgrade$0(UpgradeProcess.java:122) ~[portal-kernel.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.db.partition.util.DBPartitionUtil.forEachCompanyId(DBPartitionUtil.java:178) ~[portal-impl.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.db.BaseDB.process(BaseDB.java:465) ~[portal-impl.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.db.BaseDBProcess.process(BaseDBProcess.java:378) ~[portal-kernel.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeProcess.upgrade(UpgradeProcess.java:107) ~[portal-kernel.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeProcess.upgrade(UpgradeProcess.java:146) ~[portal-kernel.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.upgrade.PortalUpgradeProcess.doUpgrade(PortalUpgradeProcess.java:350) ~[portal-impl.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.upgrade.PortalUpgradeProcess.upgrade(PortalUpgradeProcess.java:324) ~[portal-impl.jar:?]
    ... 10 more
2024-05-23 10:12:50.345 ERROR [main][UpgradeRecorder:194] Unable to check the upgrade result due to null. Please check manually.
2024-05-23 10:12:50.364 INFO  [main][UpgradeRecorder:154] Major upgrade finished with result failure

Failed Liferay upgrade process in 35 seconds
Connecting to Gogo shell because the upgrade failed or is incomplete
Portal upgrade failed. Fix the issue and retry.


As this is not programming-related: Consider bringing it over to the Liferay Community (e.g. https://liferay.dev) where it would be on-topic. On Stackoverflow, it isn't (see [help/on-topic])

Sure thing @OlafKock. However, I have found what the issue is. Initially we have used sql-server as DB in 7.2 but upon migrating to 7.2 we have used postGres. All the boolean column in the sql-server were having data-type as "bit" but in PostGres bit is not a data-type, so we have to change all the columns DB to boolean form bit. We couldn't understand, why sql-server management studio couldn't adjust this changes when migrating the data source from sql-server to postgres.

Rather than converting through some non-Liferay tool: Have Liferay create the proper database (and indexes etc) and then move the data over to that well-known-database structure

@OlafKock Do we have such tool in Liferay which convert MS Sql-server data source to PostGresSQL? SQL-Server Management Studio, there are lot of work, we had to do manually.

No, but you can start up a new Liferay instance on an empty database, have it create the structure, then bring over the data (without DDL)

@OlafKock Got it. Let us try, if this work well then a lot of our issues are solved.
